$P$ is a $2\times 2$ real matrix such that every non-zero vector in $\mathbb R^2$ is a eigenvector

Let $P$ be a $2$x$2$ real matrix such that every non-zero vector in  $\mathbb R^2$ is a eigenvector of P. Suppose $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues of P and
$$P \left[\matrix {\sqrt2 \\ \sqrt3} \right] = \left[\matrix {2 \\ t} \right],for\,some\,\,\,t\in \mathbb R.$$ Which of the following statement is(are) true?
a.) $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$ 
b.) $\lambda_1\lambda_2 = 2$ 
c.) $\sqrt 2$ is an eigenvalue 
d.) $\sqrt 3$ is an eigenvalue

I was able to deduce that $\sqrt 2$ is an eigenvalue. But I'm unable to prove or disprove that the other eigenvalue is $\sqrt 3$ is the other eigenvalue or $\sqrt 2$ is a repeated eigenvalue.

If $v$ and $w$ are eigenvectors of a matrix with different eigenvalues, can $v+w$ also be an eigenvector?

@MikeDaas No, v+w won't be a eigenvector.

Every nonzero vector of the appropriate dimension is an eigenvector of a square matrix $A$ if and only if $A$ is a scalar multiple of the identity matrix.

Remember that eigenvectors related to distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent. Let us assume by contradiction that $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$. Since the matrix $P$ is $2\times 2$, then the eigenspaces related to $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are $1$-dimensional. Let us say that they are generated by $v_1$ and $v_2$ respectively. Then also $v_1+v_2$ is an eigenvector (let us say of eigenvalue $\lambda$) and so
$$P(v_1+v_2)=\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2=\lambda(v_1+v_2)=\lambda v_1 +\lambda v_2 \implies  (\lambda_1-\lambda)v_1+(\lambda_2-\lambda)v_2=0 \implies \lambda=\lambda_1=\lambda_2$$
that it is a contradiction.
Hence $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$, and $a)$ is false.
Instead, $c)$ is clearly true and since $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$ then $d)$ is false.
Finally, since $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\sqrt{2}$, then $\lambda_1\lambda_2=(\sqrt{2})^2=2$ and so $b)$ is true.
